# USB connection problems for BSNL DNA A201BEI modem

Tags: internet-connection

I recently got BSNL Broadband connection.

The internet is working fine in my Laptop. But the Ethernet is not working in my Desktop. So I want to connect to internet using USB.

**CASE 1 Laptop:**

I first thought of trying USB connectivity in my Laptop and then trying in Desktop.

The modem provided by BSNL is DNA A201BEI. They gave a CD (ADSL2 + CPE/Router WiFi-TA) along with it. I could find only one setup file 'VMC PPPoE Dialer Installer.msi' in it along with few Drivers for various OS. Even after installing it the USB is not working.

I also tried downloading drivers for DNA A201 BEI and followed the instructions to install the driver. After turning on the modem with USB connected, I got found new hardware for 'RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget', then the regular installation dialogs. I selected the folder where I have the drivers. Even then the setup ends unsuccessfully with the message, "**The hardware was not installed because the wizard cannot find the necessary software**".

How can I ensure USB connection.? Is there any other drivers or something that needs to be installed.? Why am I facing this problem.?

**CASE 2 Desktop:**

I am not getting any Found new hardware popup dialog at all. After connecting the modem through USB and turning on the modem, everything remains silent. Any idea of why this problem is.?

Till two months back, I was using a BSNL broadband connection in the same desktop in my home town in USB mode. Recently I shifted my PC and got a new broadband connection. The previous modem was a BSNL Huawei Quidway 1003A Modem. The new modem provided by them is DNA A201BEI. The USB cable I am using was provided for my Huawei Quidway Modem. Is this anything to do with the modem.?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry if this is not the right place for this problem. If  you could direct me to appropriate link it would be very much helpful.